# Does zfs zfs recv validate checksums?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, data-integrity, openzfs

It seems that zfs send includes a checksum for all included data (stated for instance [here](https://openzfs.org/wiki/Documentation/ZfsSend)). Is this checksum automatically verified by zfs recv? I would assume it is, but I cannot find any confirmation of this. I'm planning to use zfs send/recv to migrate a zpool to another disk and would like to be 100% sure the data is ok before I destroy the original pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From OpenZFS site, regarding [Checksums](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Basic%20Concepts/Checksums.html):

"*checksums on ZFS replication streams, **zfs send** and **zfs receive**, ensure the data received is not corrupted by intervening storage or transport mechanisms*."